# OpenStack Alarm Engine

Tags: cloud, openstack, alarm, ceilometer

What is the best architecture for development of OpenStack alarm engine? Should Ceilometer architecture be used or is it better to manually do the monitoring and alarm triggering part by using mechanism like log monitoring or SNMP?

Answer (score 0):

Considering contribute to the project Aodh (https://launchpad.net/aodh), which is split from Ceilometer project ?